# Half cooked fried fish

Tags: food-safety, fish

I had fried fish at a restaurant and it wasn’t cooked all the way. I brought it home and wondered if it was okay to finish cooking the next day or will it make me sick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Throw it away, seriously. Foodborne illness risk increases with the type of food, the conditions in which it was cooked and how long it was at room temperature. Given that it was never cooked right in the first place and it probably stood out awhile you really should play it safe on this one, it's not worth getting very sick to save a bit of food, especially since it won't have good taste or texture now anyway.

Comment: Agreed.  Some fish is fine cooked rare or medium.  But, if it is not a fish you would expect this of, served under cooked is not only wrong, it is a sign of poor attention to the food.  I would immediately question what other errors such as sanitation quality is coming out of that kitchen.  Partially cooked fish has been taken into the danger zone of bacterial and parasite growth and been allowed to stay there.  Not safe or even close to it in may book, and even if safe, quality has been trashed.

Comment: I  appreciate both of you getting back to me. Will take your advice and throw the fish out.